# Error while trying to bring up network in SLES12.1

Tags: linux-networking, opensuse, sles

I am trying to bring up the eth0 adapter in SLES12 sp1 using

```
ifup eth0
```

but every time I am getting an error saying:

```
wicked: Reading config file /etc/wicked/client.xml
wicked: Reading config file /etc/wicked/common.xml
wicked: __ni_config_parse_ifconfig_source: Adding ifconfig firmware:
wicked: __ni_config_parse_ifconfig_source: Adding ifconfig compat:
wicked: __ni_config_parse_ifconfig_source: Adding ifconfig wicked:/etc/wicked/ifconfig
wicked: Executing: /usr/sbin/wicked --debug most ifup eth0
wicked: /org/opensuse/Network/Interface.getManagedObjects failed. Server responds:
wicked: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.opensuse.Network was not provided by any .service files
wicked: Couldn't refresh list of active network interfaces
wicked: Exit with status: 1
```

The same command is working fine in SLES12.0,
I tried to restart the network service using

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

Still the issue persisted after restarting the service.

Please note I am using VSphere as the VM host and E1000 as the adapter.